# Using cheatsheet.el and adding cheats to it

Tags: package

I have downloaded the package [cheatsheel.el](https://github.com/darksmile/cheatsheet) from Melpa for use in Emacs 25.5.1 in Ubuntu. 
However, I seem unable to add cheats to it because only the command                `(cheatsheet-show)` is available and works while the commands `cheatsheet-add` and `cheatsheet-get` do not show up at all. Any help on using this package would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cheat-sheet-add` is expecting to receive a list programmatically, it is not meant to show up with an interactive user interface.  Follow the instructions in the comments beginning at line 22.  "*Quick start.  Load package.  Add your first cheat:  `(cheatsheet-add :group 'Common :key "C-x C-c" :description "leave Emacs.")`  Run `(cheatsheet-show)` and enjoy looking at your own Emacs cheatsheet.*"  You add them to your `.emacs` file, save, and restart Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist: Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cheat-sheet-add` is expecting to receive a *list* programmatically, it is not meant to show up with an interactive user interface. Follow the instructions in the comments of `cheatsheet.el` beginning at line 22.

"Quick start. Load package. Add your first cheat:

```
(cheatsheet-add :group 'Common :key "C-x C-c" :description "leave Emacs.")
```

Run `(cheatsheet-show)` and enjoy looking at your own Emacs cheatsheet."

You add the above-mentioned cheat to your `.emacs` file, save, and restart Emacs.

Comment: ~/.emacs.d/init.el is better than ~/.emacs. And you can just M-x eval-buffer and don't need to restart Emacs.